# Grepping a specific string from a file in script

Tags: bash, file, shell, unix, grep

I have following file:(A sample file with filename: 2015_09_22_processedPartnumList.txt, Location: /a/b/c/itemreport)

```
DataLoader_trace_2015_09_22_02_01_32.0956.log:INFO: 2015-09-22
Data Processing Starts : 12345678
```

I just want to get all the ids from the above file i.e. 12345678 .... (each id in a separate line, not comma separated) in a file /a/b/c/d/ids_`date +%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S`.log

I have written the following script, but the file I am getting is empty. Without showing any exception or anything. So, it is very difficult for me to identify the errors. Please tell me what is wrong in the script.

```
LOGDIR=/a/b/logdir

tr=`date +%p`
echo $tr
if [ $tr = "PM" ];
then
    date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
    echo "considering today's date for grepping logs"
else
    date=`date -d '1 day ago' +%Y-%m-%d`
    echo "considering yesterday's date for grepping logs as job run is delayed"
fi

ITEM_FILE=/a/b/c/d/ids_`date +%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S`.log
```

After implementing grep in PCRE, I am getting this and not any ids are being copied into the new file.

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports PCRE, you can do:

```
grep -Po '.*:\s\K\d+$' /a/b/c/itemreport/2015_09_22_processedPartnumList.txt \
      >/apps/feeds/out/catalog/ItemPartnumbers_"$(date '+%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')".log
```

- `.*:\s` will match upto the space after `:`, `\K` will discard the match
- `\d+$` will match our desired portion i.e. the digits till the end of the line

**Example:**

```
% grep -Po '.*:\s\K\d+$' 2015_09_22_processedPartnumList.txt \
                       >ItemPartnumbers_"$(date '+%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')".log

% cat ItemPartnumbers_09_11_2015_11_30_49.log 
13982787
14011550
13984790
13984791
14176509
14902623
14924193
14924194
13982787
46795670
46795671
```

Comment: Sorry, But I did not understand  '.*:\s\K\d+$' , please explain this briefly if possible. Also, is this part correct: `date "+%Y_%m_%d"`_processedPartnumList.txt, because my main doubt is in this date thing.

Comment: Please look at the edited question once again, I am not getting the partnumbers as you did with grep with PCRE.

Comment: @tanmay2507 Seems your grep does not support PCRE, which OS are you using?

Comment: Mac OSX Yosemite, Version 10.10.5

Comment: @tanmay2507 hmmm...this solution won't work then as the default `grep` of Mac does not support PCRE..you can install GNU grep to have PCRE enabled `grep`..

Comment: Works with Mac OS X 10.10.5: `grep -o "[0-9]\{3,\}$" /a/b/c/itemreport/2015_09_22_processedPartnumList.txt \
      >/apps/feeds/out/catalog/ItemPartnumbers_"$(date '+%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')".log`

Answer (score 0):

That's not very good solution, but it's working.

```
cat your\ file | cut -d ':' -f2-2 | tr -d INFO
```

Comment: .....
O
 14515220\
O
 13982787\
O
 46795670\
O
 46795672\
O
 46795675\
O
 46795679\
O
 10001857\
}

I am getting this as my output. So, why I am getting this 'O' everywhere and is there any way to just extract the digit part and remove the '/' after each partnumber.